# Joda Time: How can I divide a Period into many Intervals?

Tags: java, jodatime

Im new to Joda Time and would like to create an equal (x) number of Intervals from a known time Period. How can I do this?

So for example. I have a period of 3hours and want to create 3 intervals. Each interval would be an hour.

Comment: I have tried looking around the API but cannot find any methods to help do this. Looks like I will have to do it with some arithmatic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  int x = //...
  DateTime dateFrom = new DateTime(/* ... */);
  DateTime dateTo = new DateTime(/* ... */);
  long singlePart = (dateTo.getMillis() - dateFrom.getMillis()) / x;
  List<Interval> result = new ArrayList<Interval>();

  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
     result.add(new Interval(dateFrom.plusMillis((int) singlePart * i), dateFrom.plusMillis((int) singlePart * (i + 1))));      
  }
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid something messy like this, and hoped for a nice method call.

Comment: I working with Joda-time (1.6.x) for a long time, but don't know this method. May be in feature versions this method is